No background in 24.04
After upgrading to 24.04 I have a black background in Gnome. Looking at the "Appearance" tab in Tweaks the default background should be "Bodacious_bovine_by_oklopfer_light.png", where is this background to be found?

I would gues it is in package ubuntu-wallpapers-mantic
